# Highchart with external CSV (in external domain)

Tags: javascript, json, csv, asp-classic, highcharts

I can draw charts with JSON values, in another domain. I use ajax, and a callback to make crossdomain and get values.

```
function drawChart() {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart01',
            marginRight: 0,
            marginTop: 60,
            type: 'column',
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 15,
                beta: 15,
                viewDistance: 25,
                depth: 90
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                depth: 90
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'CSV Values'
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: '',
                margin: 0
            },
            categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Title'
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: []
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://<external_path>/json.asp?callback=?",
        data: 'show=impression',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var intSeries = data.length;
            var cont = 0;
            if (intSeries > 0) {
                intSeries--;
                options.xAxis.categories = data[cont]['data'];
                while (cont < intSeries) {
                    options.series[cont] = data[cont + 1];
                    cont++;
                }
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

In `json.asp` (in another server) I return json values with callback:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json"
dim strJSON
strJSON = "" & _
    "[" & _
        "{" & _
            """name"": ""General Values""," & _
            """data"": [""Porcentaje""]" & _
        "}, {" & _
            """name"": ""Value 1""," & _
            """data"": [34.60436]" & _
        "}, {" & _
            """name"": ""Value 2""," & _
            """data"": [12.30343]" & _
        "}, {" & _
            """name"": ""Value 3""," & _
            """data"": [53.30423]" & _
        "}" & _
    "]"
response.write request.QueryString("callback") & "(" & strJSON2 & ")"
```

It works fine. My problem is to run charts using an external CSV or XML. I've proved some ways, but I always get an error **`401 Unauthorized`**. I change from `dataType: "json"` to `dataType: "text"` or `dataType: "xml"` (CSV and XML mode), and with the new external path, but it doesn't work.

How I would get values from an external CSV or XML file?? I can't put on my server that files, so I need it was in another server.

**UPDATE:**
I've added on my server to enable CORS with this values:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:     Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:     GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:      *
```

and I've modified ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://<external_path>/test.csv",
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "text",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
    //-- I've tried to authenticate without success
    //beforeSend: function (request){ request.setRequestHeader( ""Authorization"", btoa('<user>:<pass>')); },
    success: function (data) {
        //---- Code to get values ----//
    }
});
```

After the changes, I go on with 401 error.

Comment: Have you set CORS on your external server? To allow traffic and AJAX requests from different domain.

Comment: I'll try to set enabled...

Comment: So you have authorization. Have you passed credentials along with the request?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to run a simple proxy on your server which fetches the data for you. i.e. you request the data from your proxy process, which requests the data for from the remote system and returns it to you.

This problem is a classic example of needing to get round cross-domain restrictions. There are plenty of questions and answers about this topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: I've already thought about your way. It'll be my last resort. Thanks.
I've read and read about cross-domain restrinctions but I don't get success.